# Browser not showing or parsing the content of an include file

Tags: php

I have a form with a textarea control, mainly to input an article that consists of pure text... Inside the textarea control, i have text like

[image]

I submit the form and save the textarea data into a database field. So far so good..

[image: the correct data appears in the database]

When in a browser, i'm trying to output the database field, but i dont get the content of the php include file, instead i get something like the following:

[image]

The php tags are commented!!!

Why is the browser not showing/parsing the content of the include file?

UPDATED:
this is the content of test.php

```
<?php
   echo test;
?>
```

this is the code of article.php

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/global.inc.php');
require_once('../includes/connection.inc.php');

if (isset($_GET['article']) && is_numeric($_GET['article'])) {
   $get_article = (int)$_GET['article'];

   $conn = connect('read');

   $sql = 'SELECT article.article_id, article.title, article.description, article.article, article.seo_url
        FROM article
        WHERE article.article_id = ?';

   $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

   $stmt->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $get_article);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   $stmt->bind_result($articleid, $title, $description, $article, $seourl);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->free_result();
   $stmt->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     echo $title;
     echo $article;
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: It sounds like you're making a giant security hole.

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing include up with echo, your question looks really strange. As SLaks suggested, without code I do not think we can help

Comment: Does the file containing the `include()` directive have `.php` extension?

Comment: I've added some images to explain better... english is not my first language... i apologize

Comment: Something in your code is adding comments around php tags.

Comment: i added the code as requested

Comment: @Marco can you add the file names to your question, above the code examples? Like: 'this is the code of article.php', this is the code of 'xyz.html'

Comment: i just updated..sorry for the html typo

Comment: Ok! now I understand whats going on. You are saving the php code to your database and expecting it beeing executed in browser. This will not work as I told in my answer. You cannot do want you are trying. Btw, it is a big security whole.

Comment: thanks. what do you suggest i should do? The reason i want to have an include file is because that file will contains dynamic data and i dont want to enter that data on each article.. just in one place and change in the future when needed...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23534/discussion-between-marco-and-hek2mgl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you misunderstood where PHP is executed. PHP is executed on the server and not in the browser. You'll have to make sure the site will be parsed on server by PHP. You'lll mostly do it by using a PHP enabled webserver and giving the file a .php extension.

The php code isn't outcommented. Thats just your debugging tool that shows it outcommented because the opening `<?php` would lead to invalid HTML. It could also be possible that HTML parser of your browser adds the `<!--` to avoid problems with the opening php. I don't know this exactly.

You can verify this by viewing the raw html source code and you'll see there is no magic that comments out your php :)

Comment: ok, your explanation make sense... how do i go about doing what i want to do? Is there a solution?

Comment: What is the file extension of the site? .php?

Comment: can you prepare a simple file with this content: `<?php phpinfo();?>` name it `test.php` put it beside article php and open it in your web browser. What do you see?

Comment: i see the all of the information and configuration of the server... by the way im on a shared server